# Property transfer in SoapUi

Tags: java, soapui

I am running a soapui xml using SoapUITestCaseRunner. In xml I have 4 test suites.Ist is an authentication suite
where i get a authentication token while running it.But when I try to run the second suite which use the authentication token
,I am unable to get it.How to run two testsuites with the context information saved using SoapUITestCaseRunner

Answer (score 0):

There are too many possible answers!

The easiest solution is probably to use a [Property Transfer step](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.html) in your first test Case, and transfer the value to the test suite level. Then in your subsequent tests just use [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html).